# jQuery: Trigger function when window width matches any value in array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, responsive-design, window-resize

I'm working on a responsive site and have several specific functions I need to fire at certain points on window resize: when the window reaches a defined "mobile width, when it reaches a defined "desktop" width, and when it reaches any width in a specified array of numbers (my CSS breakpoints).

Here is a stripped down fiddle showing where I'm at (all the appended paragraph elements are placeholders for where my functions will go): http://jsfiddle.net/ygwug/

As you can see by resizing the window, I've gotten the mobile / desktop check to work, but the breakpoint checker is not working. The code specifically related to this is as follows:

```
var breakpoints = [320, 480, 550, 650, 720, 790, 1000, 1190];
    window_w = $wind.width();

var breakpointHit = function() {
    $('body').append("<p>Breakpoint was hit!</p>");
}

if ( $.inArray( window_w, breakpoints ) > -1 ) {
    breakpointHit();
}
```

From what I understand, $.inArray should return -1 if the value does not exist in the array, and the index of the value if it does exist, which is why I used "> -1" to determine if the value exists in the array. But as I'm not seeing any syntax errors in Dev Tools, there must be an error in my logic somewhere.

If anyone could help point me in the right direction, I would really appreciate it. Thanks!

Comment: Tried your jsfiddle as is - seems to be working fine. Break point is hit. Getting the window to exact width to one of you values in array is tough though :-)

Comment: Same conclusion as Fergus.  I, however, couldn't get my window to that exact width.

Comment: Oh, sorry if that wasn't clear. I want the function to fire when the breakpoint is passed, so as you resize the window narrower and wider a few times, you should see several "Breakpoint was hit!" messages dispersed between the desktop / mobile messages. Right now all I'm seeing are either "The window is now mobile." or "The window is now desktop."

Comment: @Fergus @user1167442 That's because doing an exact width test is not actually what you want to perform with responsive design. Responsive CSS selectors are usually when `max-width: px` meaning the `max-width` of the page is the pixel value or smaller (i.e. `<`)

Comment: @izuriel Yes, exactly. I want this function to fire when the mark is passed, not necessarily stopped on exactly. Similar functionality to CSS media queries.

Comment: Check my answer, the JSFiddle should have what you need then.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check this modification of your original jFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/hKRrm/1/

What I changed:

- Moved your breakpoint test into the window resize
- allows `breakpointHit` to accept the breakpoint that was hit
- modify your breakpoint test so that it's `window_w < breakpoint` as most likely intended (`==` would never get you anywhere)
- Add in cache of current breakpoint to prevent it from firing more than once
- moved the `mobileCheck` call into the `breakpointHit` function where it should be. By that I mean you only want to check to see if you are on mobile if a breakpoint is hit, not all the time.

This may or may not answer your question, but this is what I interpreted your question as asking for.

Comment: Ah, this is awesome! Thanks for the work, I will definitely learn a lot digging through your code, this is even better functionality than I originally intended.

Comment: @R.J. Glad to hear it. You were most of the way there, I just modified it slightly so it's not like you were very far off from the right course.